# Spherical surface charge distribution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

I have a problem that sounds like this:

> Consider a spherical surface of radius $b$ with the fixed charge distribution $\sigma(\theta)=\sigma_0 \cos(\theta)$, $\theta$ being the polar angle. Calculate the electric field inside and outside of the surface $E_i(r,\theta), E_e(r,\theta)$.

I know that, to find the charge, I have to integrate the charge distribution over the whole sphere. The problem is, when I integrate the distribution $\sigma(\theta)=\sigma_0 \cos(\theta)$ varying the $\theta$ from 0 to $\pi$ and the angle $\phi$ from 0 to $2\pi$, it is equal to zero.

Comment: You are not asked to find the charge. You know the charge. You're asked to find the field. And yes the net charge is zero.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 1):

That's true, the net charge is zero, but there's no problem with that. It doesn't mean that the electric field is zero everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you are supposed to use the spherical multipole expansion. Notice that $\sigma \propto Y^0_1$. You now should be able simply to plug everything into the formulas to get the result.